# windows batch escape whole string

Tags: batch-file

Ok. this is a self updating batch file. I just simplified the problem from a bigger file.
this is a windows batch file(.bat) that upon execution should open itself and update first line

```
SET variableName=D:\Data
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A i=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "%0"^&cd.^>"%0"') do (
  set /A i=!i!+1
  if !i! EQU 1 (
    echo SET variableName=D:\Data2>>%0
  ) else (
    echo %%f>>%0
  )
)
endlocal
```

so let explain the situation.
i have **!i!** variable in lines **5** and **6**. after executing this file, the variable in each line will replace by line number. it obviously because of **echo %%f>>%0** that could not ignore and escape variable.
and my question is how to solve this problem?
another less problem is that the above code ignores spaces at beginning of line (indents) and generates a flat file.
the result of executing this file is:

```
SET variableName=D:\Data2
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A i=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "%0"^&cd.^>"%0"') do (
set /A i=5+1
if 6 EQU 1 (
echo SET variableName=D:\Data2>>%0
) else (
echo %%f>>%0
)
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping expansion of the variable when executing the file is as simple as turning delayed expansion off prior to the line that updates the file, and pairing it with an endlocal.

Retaining the space / tab formatting is achieved by including delims= in the For loop options.

```
Set variableName=D:\Data
Setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
Set /A i=0
For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('type "%0"^&cd.^>"%0"') do (
  Set /A i+=1
  If !i! EQU 1 (
    Echo SET variableName=D:\Data2>>%0
  ) Else (
    Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(%%f>>%0
    Endlocal
  )
)
Endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set "variableName=D:\Data"
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem !test! exclaimations, %test% percentages

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('
    type "%~f0" ^&
    ^> "%~f0" echo set "variableName=D:\Data2"
') do (
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    >> "%~f0" echo %%A
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

You can avoid counting as `skip=1` can be used to skip the first line. Use `delims=` to avoid delimiting the line. `tokens=*` ignores delimiters at start of the line and get the remainder of the line so that can be omitted for this task.

The new first line is now in the `for` loop command instead of erasing the file to empty. If you `echo` more lines, then increase the `skip` number.

Also may need to use `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` so exclamation marks are retained.

Modifying the same file that is being read can a risk, though I assume you understand the risk.